# Удаление содержимого окна и заполнение другой информацией в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть часть кода, где всё обвёрнуто в функции, кроме параметров основного окна.

```
import *******

root = tk.Tk()
...
...

def login_screen():

    global login_input, password_input

    login_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Login', fg='white', bg='black', font='Archangelsk 10')
    login_label.place(x = 280, y = 150)

    login_input = tk.Entry(root, width = 40)
    login_input.place(x = 175, y = 180)

    password_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Password', fg='white', bg='black', font='Archangelsk 10')
    password_label.place(x = 270, y = 210)

    password_input = tk.Entry(root, width = 40)
    password_input.place(x = 175, y = 240)

    auth_btn = tk.Button(root, text = 'Sign in', command=check_data)
    auth_btn.place(x = 175, y = 270)

    start_screen_btn = tk.Button(root, text = 'Registration', command = clear_screen)
    start_screen_btn.place(x = 345, y = 270)

def clear_screen():
    pass
```

Типикал форма авторизации. Теперь, при нажатии на "Registration" необходимо удалить всё содержимое окна и вывести форму регистрации, а также добавить кнопку: "cancel", которая вернётся на первый этап и отобразит содержимое login_screen. Нужен своего рода переключатель.

Код за меня писать не нужно, просто не до конца понятен сам механизм для реализации данной идеи. Пожалуйста, в двух словах, поставьте на правильный путь! :)

Comment: Все содержимое окна, которое потом нужно удалять, помещаете в один общий фрейм, потом для этого фрейма вызываете метод destroy

Comment: Обычно такое делается двумя окнами. Одно окно для логина, другое для регистрации. Но если хочется именно модифицировать окно (хотя обычно такое поведение окна считается "плохим тоном", ведь это не браузер), то можно воспользоваться методами виджетов  `XXX_forget()` (`place_forget()` в вашем случае) чтобы удалить элементы с окна. Ну а дальше наполняете окно снова уже новыми элементами. `XXX_forget()` не уничтожает сами виджеты, а просто убирает их с окна (т.е. потом достаточно их будет снова разместить командой `place()`).

Comment: Второй вариант рабочий, даже не знал о таком методе. С первым сейчас буду детальнее разбираться. Спасибо большое за хелпу! <3